# unable to connect to postgres hosted on ubuntu VM on azure from myBinder

Tags: postgresql, azure, sqlalchemy, mybinder

I've setup a postgres database on an ubuntu VM on azure.

I use this simple conda env to access my database from jupyter :

```
conda create -n test python=3.8.5 pandas psycopg2 ipython-sql sqlalchemy jupyterlab
```

I can connect to this database from jupyter using sqlalchemy from my desktop :

```
%load_ext sql
```

And then :

```
%sql postgresql://user:password@server.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:5432/test_db
```

But when I do the same from myBinder (or from some other locations behind proxy), it can't connect and it times out.

It seems to be related with the mybinder security policy, can I set up something to go through?

Comment: I think your title should say 'MyBinder' and not 'some location'? Unless I am misunderstanding. In answer to the question in the text, MyBinder blocks a lot of ports for security reasons, see [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/mybinder.org-deploy/issues/694#issuecomment-414792700).

Comment: Yes you are right. I also have the problem for some clients connecting from secure environnement. But mybinder is more reproductible. Thanks for the link @Wayne!

Comment: I have tested with a well configured ssl postgres server, and I still can't connect from mybinder